# add webparts to the right hand side of master page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage

I want to add webparts to right hand side of the master page as they are repeating on every page. I reduced the placemainholder main area to create space on the right but i cannot reach to that point using div tags. I can only add webparts below the palceholdermain contentplaceholder but not on the side.

[image]

Comment: have tried adding `float:right` for your right pane...

Comment: Yes, I tried float:right.. it goes to the right but still it is below placeholdermain.

Comment: Then, Try to give both `left navigation` and `PlaceHolderMain` to `float:left` and `right pane` to `position:relative`

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the master page and add the 1*3 table in the right-hand side of the master page.

Then add the announcements web part, calendar web part and other web part in the each cell in the table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. In the picture, I can see that you are adding a table with 3 rows on the page and not on the master page. I do not think we can edit the master page via browser, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You could edit the master page in SharePoint designer 2010 and add the table in the page